# How to add a different type of item in the ListView using SimpleAdapter?

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I want to add a different type of item (like a simple textview) to the last position in my `ListView`.

I extends the `SimpleAdapter` and override some methods:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    if (super.getCount() == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return super.getCount() + 1;
    }
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    if (position == getCount() - 1) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return super.getItem(position);
    }
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v;
    if (position == getCount() - 1) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            v = new TextView(mContext);
        } else {
            v = convertView;
        }

        return v;
    } else {
        return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    }
}
```

But it did not work. What is the problem or how to add one?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a footer instead, in your activity try

```
getListView().addFooter(View.inflate(R.layout.my_footer, null));
```

You have to do this before you add the adapter to the listview.

Comment: my code: getListView().addFooterView(View.inflate(this, R.layout.footer, null));

Comment: ahh yes I forgot it wants a parent arguments. Thanks